# Listening to events in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

In my application, the user can toggle to lock mode when he wants to lock the position of a specific rectangle (by clicking on a little circle in its top-right corner).

So, to remove event listener: `group.off('click dblclick');`

After that, he can toggle back to "free mode", so he can drag, resize, do anything. Is there some code that does the opposite of the above line? I mean a line that allows listening to that specific mouse event. Something like `group.on('click dblclick');` (this one is not working of course).

I tried `group.listening(true);` and false, but the problem is that the circle is added to that group. So it's a specific event that I want to remove, and then listen to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for click events on the stage and turn on group-listening of the user clicks outside the group:

Disclaimer -- here's some example code, but I haven't tested it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(stage.getContent()).on('click', function (event) {

    // if the group is already listening, just exit

    if(group.listening){return;}

    // get the current mouse position

    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);

    // get the current group position

    var left=group.x();
    var right=left+group.width();
    var top=group.y();
    var bottom=top+group.height();

    // if the click is outside the group,
    // turn the groups listening on 

    if(!(mouseX>left && mouseX<right && mouseY>top && mouseY<bottom)){
        group.listening(true);
    }

});
```

**[ Update: non-jQuery alternate ]**

You can listen for mouse clicks without jQuery using stage.on('contentClick',function(){}):

```
stage.on('contentClick',function(){
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
    console.log("contentclick",mouseX,mouseY);
});
```

Comment: I added to my answer illustrating a non-jquery method for listening to clicks on the container.  Cheers!

Comment: I tried it, stage.on('contentclick',...) binds the clicks on everything in the stage, even on that group that I'm talking about. example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfvud/ . I want to manipulate events on the components of the group (specifically the circle that toggle motion, and a little anchor for resizing) so that when I lock motion, the resizing in blocked as well.